# Why is PHP file append only wholly successful in 99.7% attempts

Tags: javascript, php, logging, cross-browser, cross-platform

I have a Javascript app running on a wide range of platforms.
(I try to keep the list of client devices as large as possible, including early Android phones and early iPhones, using caniuse.com).

Each time the client app's data changes, the new data is appended to a plain text log file on the server.  The appends are a single string of between about 20 characters and 70 characters.

## The problem

Every so often - about one time in 250 - the first 6 to 20 characters of the append go AWOL.

The JavaScript app on the client device sends the data by XmlHttpRequest to PHP 5.5.10 on the Windows PC, which then writes to the diskfile on the mounted partition of the NAS (mounted as a Windows drive letter on the PC).

The PHP is running on a Mongoose web server on Windows 7, and the data is then stored on hard drive on a domestic Network Attached Storage device on the server's network. (A Debian Linux NAS appliance) The NAS can sometimes take several seconds to spin up the hard disc.

Only one client device is working with any given plain text file, but up to 10 client devices might be accessing their respective plain text files at any given time.

## The questions

Is it something that will go away if I fix the latencies on the server+NAS combination?  (By putting the files locally on the server, for example)

Or is there a way to make the writes guaranteed by using new facilities?  Say, for example, by writing to a SQLite table rather than a plain text file, or a Couchbase db or a CouchDB or somesuch.

As long as the client device's involvement stays as a simple XmlHttpRequest, I can keep the wide range of client devices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough information to go on here, too many systems and too little information. The *only* thing I can think of is that it's a concurrency issue.

If you are writing to a file on disk, what happens if two requests come in at the same time? If you read, then write, you could end up with the second request being overwritten by the first. For example:

```
Process 1 receives data Y.
Process 2 receives data Z.
Process 1 reads data X from the disk.
Process 2 reads data X from the disk.
Process 1 writes to the disk, data is now XY
Process 2 writes to the disk, data is now XZ
```

In this example `Y` is lost.

If you use a database (MySQL, Couch, etc), it should matter less if the data has changed between reading and writing. On the rare occasion where I've had to read something and edit that exact thing, I use a query something along the lines of

```
UPDATE table SET data = "XY" WHERE data = "X"
```

This means if the data changed after I read X, it doesn't update the field, which is something I can observe and handle in the code.

Answer (score 0):

PHP documentation for fwrite says that it is an atomic action - either everything should be written, or nothing should be written.

This points to it being a bug in PHP.

I've submitted a bug report.

Any ideas on work-rounds?

(In tests today, none of the writes were partials.  12 went missing, 17 happened out-of-order - i.e. in a different order to the order the client sent the info in, out of a total of 42).

Comment: I've changed the
_fopen($filename,"a") ; fwrite($stuff) ; fclose()_
sequences to
_file_put_contents($filename, $stuff, FILE_APPEND | 
LOCK_EX)_

This adds an implicit file lock to the process, released by fclose().

This should make all writes either succeed, or fail completely.  (As opposed to the current situation where, very occasionally, they fail partially)